# How to accept android sdk license agreements when 'sdkmanager --licenses' won't work in 2020

Tags: android, licensing

I have installed 2 sdks in my Android folder aka in my
(I'm on windows)
    C:\Users\XmyusernameX\Local\Android.
One called \Sdk and another called \OldSdk.
\OldSdk contains the one downloaded from android studio. It didn't come with the command line \tools folder so I put it in there myself. (I downloaded it from https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads)
When I try to do:

```
cd C:\Users\XmyusernameX\Local\Android\OldSdk\tools\bin
```

then:

```
sdkmanager.bat --licenses
```

I get:

```
 Error: Could not find or load main class com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli
```

So when I try to do the other one (I got this one from like a installer or something I don't know honestly)

When I do:

```
cd C:\Users\XmyusernameX\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin
```

then:

```
sdkmanager.bat --licenses
```

I get:

```
Error: Unknown argument --licenses
Usage: 
  sdkmanager [--uninstall] [<common args>] \
    [--package_file <package-file>] [<packages>...]
  sdkmanager --update [<common args>]
  sdkmanager --list [<common args>]
... it goes on...
```

So is there like a special place I need to download something like the \tools folder? Or something I need to configure?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nevermind I got it. All you have to do is go into Android Studio, open a project, go into 
*Tools > SDK Manager > SDK tools*,

Check Android SDK tools,
click apply then let it do it's thing, then go into the command line go to the path:

```
cd C:\Users\XmyusernameX\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin
```

Then run:

```
sdkmanager.bat --licenses
```

Then accept all finally it should all work!

Comment: Would be still nice to know how it is working from command line.

Comment: I don't know. I had to reinstall my OS since this post.

Comment: In Ubuntu there is no SDK Manager under Tools

Comment: Under Linux, if installed through Android Studio, `sdkmanager` should be in `~/Android/Sdk/tools/bin`

Comment: Absolutely horrible design.

Answer (score 0):

This came up whilst googling the solution so I will pop the Linux solution here, which may also help windows users.
The tools to accept the license have been moved.

Here's how I got the tools in Android Studio(Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 2) on Linux.

**1. Click Tools > SDK Manager**

[image: tools_sdk]

**2. Along the top, we have tabs.**

Go to the SDK Tools tab and enable "Android SDK Command-line Tools(latest)".

Then Click Apply

[image: sdktoolstabv3]

**3. Remember this path, we will need to open a terminal and cd to the SDK directory.**
[image: getsdkpath]

**4. Open a terminal, cd to the SDK directory**

Type the below into a terminal, replacing the sdk folder with the one you found in step #3.

```
# cd to the sdk folder
cd $HOME/Android/SDK
cd cmdline-tools/latest/bin
./sdkmanager --licenses
# press 'y' to accept the licenses.
```

And yes, you lucky winner, you have just accepted the google license. Thank you for participating in the license agreement marathon. And thank you to google for making it such a pleasure to accept.
[image: doneit]